# StreamReader save ReadLine to string and use it in if

Tags: c#, webclient, streamreader

Hi I want to save the output from reader.ReadToEnd() to a string and check if the string is "Access" but I don't know how to do it.

```
string url = "https://mywebsite.com/check.php";
Stream mystream = client.OpenRead(url);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mystream);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd()); //The text will be "Access"

//Pseudecode start
string line = reader.ReadToEnd();

if (line == "Access")
{
    useraccess = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
mystream.Close();
```

Comment: [`ReadToEnd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a `string`, so it looks like your code should work properly. What did you expect your code to do and what is actually happening?

Comment: you already posted a code that does what you desribe, what's the question?

Comment: If all you want to get from a server is a string, why do you mess around with all the streams and StreamReader? `WebClient` has methods that directly return the server response as a string, which would replace your whole stream/StreamReader thingamabob with a single line of code...

Comment: @elgonzo do you mean going with client.DownloadData? because it's returning more then it should and I don't know how to use it that it only returns the part which I need. Maybe you can show me how?

Comment: Also, if you call ReadToEnd() twice, the second will return empty string: ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader_ReadToEnd

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the stream twice without any sort of reset, it would be more advisable to read it only once.  Also you should be disposing of your stream and streamreader appropriately. See the following:

```
        string url = "https://mywebsite.com/check.php";
        string remoteData = null;
        using (Stream mystream = client.OpenRead(url))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mystream))
            remoteData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(remoteData); //The text will be "Access"

        //Pseudecode start
        if (remoteData == "Access")
        {
            useraccess = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
```

This should work under the assumption that ReadToEnd() is returning what you wanted it to return.  I don't know what your endpoint looks like so I can't verify.

Comment: Yeah since the php file is only returning this line, this is working. Thank you